# TypeError: history.push is not a function: How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have these two forms and I wanted to redirect the user to the homepage after the first form submit `handleSubmit`. I have already declared `withRouter` and used it. But, it still has the error:

> TypeError: history.push is not a function

Below are the codes:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";


import firebase from "firebase/app";

const Session = ({ id }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  ....other codes above

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(id);
      const ref = userRef.set(
        {
          items: {
            id,
            ...variable names here
          },
        },

        { merge: true }
      );

      console.log(" saved");
      stocksCounter();
      history.push("/");  <-- history.push
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  

  //2nd submit-----------------------------------------------------------
  ...other codes here
  const handleSubmit2 = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(scanResult);
      const ref = userRef.set(
        {
          items: {
           ..variable names here
          },
        },
        { merge: true }
      );

      console.log(" saved");
      stocksCounter();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
  ....codes here
  );
};

export default withRouter(Session);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `useHistory` hook.

```
const history = useHistory();
history.push('/')
```

Answer (score 2):

though there is a global history object, you need to use the history from react-router using `props.history` which is injected using `withRouter`

Answer (score 1):

First import useHistory from react
Then add inside the handleSubmit const history = useHistory()
And in the end history.push('/') - router

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).